# How do you create a Mail Merge template that contains an object's custom fields?

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, office-connect, mail-merge

I am trying to create a Mail Merge Template in Word 2013 for an instance in Salesforce that has Extended Mail Merge enabled. The "template" document needs to populate information from fields on the Opportunity object, including some custom fields there.

Since Office Connect does not work with Office 2013, I inserted new fields using the API Name of the Opportunity object's fields in a Word document (using *Insert > Quick Parts > Fields > MergeField*).

The Word document looked something like this,

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet `<<Opportunity_StandardField>>`, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec odio nec magna laoreet consectetur `<<Opportunity_Custom_Field_API_Name__c>>`.

When I tested the Mail Merge, the document that arrived in my inbox contained information from the Opportunity object's standard fields, however, no information from the custom fields appeared. Rather, a `________` appears instead.

How do you create a Mail Merge template that contains an object's custom fields? In my case, the Opportunity object's custom fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, getting the mail merge fields correct is a pain! Use this useful url to debug/check the available field names and the values for any record:

https://na1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.SForceMailMerge?id=00230000012XXX0

Setting the “na1″ to your server, and the id to the lead, contact, account record you are debugging.

This is the XML that MS Word pulls down when it is doing the merge action.

[image: merge xml]

Comment: This solution is no longer working. Anyone have an updated idea on how to do this? I am looking to merge a field from the relationships tab.

Comment: the URL still works for me - you need to udpate NA1 to your server.  see this article : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199283&type=1